# django Rest Framework filter by date range

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have view class given

```
class eventList(ListAPIView):

       queryset = Event.objects.all().filter(is_active=1, is_approved=1)
       serializer_class = eventSerialiser
       filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter]
       search_fields = ['event_name', 'event_address', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 
                         'age_max', 'age_min','event_organizer__name', 'event_type__name', 
                         'event_city__name', 'event_tag__name']
       filterset_fields = ['event_name', 'start_date', 'start_time', 'end_date', 'end_time', 
                           'age_max', 'age_min', 'event_organizer', 'event_type', 'event_city', 
                           'event_tag']
       ordering_fields = '__all__'
       ordering = ['-id']
```

All filters working fine but how i can get data against date rang `start_date` and `end_date`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This work for me.

- double underscore **gte** is for greater than equal to
- double underscore **gt** is for greater than
- double underscore **lte** is for less than equal to
- double underscore **lt** is for less than

  ```
    filterset_fields = {
        'start_date':['gte', 'lte', 'exact', 'gt', 'lt'],
        'id':['exact'],
        'event_name':['exact'],
        'start_time':['exact'],
        'end_date':['exact'],
        'end_time':['exact'],
        'age_max':['gte', 'lte', 'exact', 'gt', 'lt'],
        'age_min':['gte', 'lte', 'exact', 'gt', 'lt'],
        'event_organizer__name':['exact'],
        'event_type__name':['exact'],
        'event_city__name':['exact'],'event_tag__name':['exact']
    }
  ```

Comment: Also ` 'start_date': ['range']` , If start_datetime then `  'start_date':['date__range']`

Comment: how can i perform a single field range filtration ? and i am using ApiView

Comment: I cannot use the above syntax in my DRF viewsets:
`filterset_fields = {
   'created_at':['date__range']
        }`.
 I get `invalid syntax: 'created_at':['date__range']`

Comment: I got it working, I guess I need to specify the filter type for every filterable field.
Now I just wonder what would be the query parameter for `date__range`

Answer (score 1):

I am using filter - DateFromToRangeFilter. https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#datefromtorangefilter

```
class BookFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr="gte")
    max_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr="lte")
    start_date = filters.DateFilter(lookup_expr="gte")
    end_date = filters.DateFilter(lookup_expr="lte")

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [
            "authors",
            "publishing_house",
            "is_bestseller",
            "category",
            "min_price",
            "max_price",
            "start_date",
            "end_date",
        ]

from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class BookListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """List of all books"""

    serializer_class = catalog.serializers.BookCatalogSerializer
    pagination_class = ProductsPagination
    queryset = Book.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = BookFilter
```

Result SQL

```
WHERE ("catalog_book"."is_active" = true AND "catalog_product"."start_date" >= '2016-01-01T00:00:00+03:00'::timestamptz AND "catalog_product"."end_date" <= '2016-01-01T00:00:00+03:00'::timestamptz)
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Your anwer is on django-filter, I'm asking django rest framework filter

Comment: @SohailAhmad I've updated my answer. I use it with rest framework filter

Comment: appreciate your effort but its not working. i want to filter data from two date **start_date** and **end_date** eg `select * from events where start_date >= '2019-11-01' And end_date <= '2019-11-30'`

Answer (score 1):

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#daterangefilter

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

class F(FilterSet):
    date = DateFromToRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['date']

# Range: Comments added between 2016-01-01 and 2016-02-01
f = F({'date_after': '2016-01-01', 'date_before': '2016-02-01'})

# Min-Only: Comments added after 2016-01-01
f = F({'date_after': '2016-01-01'})

# Max-Only: Comments added before 2016-02-01
f = F({'date_before': '2016-02-01'})
```