# Django-filter BaseInFilter

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-filters

I am currently trying to use BaseInFilter. Users can input the ids separated by commas like the one shown in the picture. I want to make a validator(or regulate user's input) so that the user can only input integers here.

[image]

If the user enters characters, the Django backend will throw out this error.
[image: error]

I have also tried this:

```
class BaseIntegerFilter(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.NumberFilter):
    pass

class HardwareFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    queryset = Hardware
    serializer_class = HardwareSerializer
    id = filters.BaseIntegerFilter(field_name="id", label="Comma separated list of hardware IDs", help_text="Comma separated list of hardware IDs")
```

But this solution doesn't allow me to input commas in the textbox anymore.

Could anyone help? Any help will be really appreatiated!

Comment: Code `id = filters.BaseInFilter ....`, maybe it should using `BaseIntegerFilter` ?

Comment: Also why do you set `queryset` and `serializer_class` on the _`FilterSet`_?

Comment: @MahrusKhomaini thanks for pointing out! that's a typo. I have edited the question

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I just started to learning how to use django-filter. Should I put them anywhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some guidance with regards to usage.

### Using `filterset_class` with `BaseInFilter`

- https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class
- https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter
- Note that the parameters `queryset` and `serializer_class` are fields of [view](https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.generics/GenericAPIView.html) classes, not filter classes.

views.py:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import viewsets

from my_app.filters import MyFilter
from my_app.models import MyModel
from my_app.serializers import MySerializer


class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = MyFilter
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

filters.py:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import BaseInFilter, FilterSet, NumberFilter

from my_app.models import MyModel


class _NumberInFilter(BaseInFilter, NumberFilter):
    pass


class MyFilter(FilterSet):
    id__in = _NumberInFilter(field_name='id', lookup_expr='in')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

HTTP request (numbers):

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/my_view_set/?id__in=2,5,6
[{"id":5,"name":"Some name 5"},{"id":2,"name":"Some name 2"},{"id":6,"name":"Some name 6"}]
```

- Note that the lookup in the query parameter was `id__in` and not just `id`.
- `curl` was used here. For easier access, you can also enter it in a browser, Postman, etc.

HTTP request (numbers and letters):

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/my_view_set/?id__in=2,5FD,6
{"id__in":["Enter a number."]}
```

### Using `filterset_fields`

- https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html#using-the-filterset-fields-shortcut
- https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#generating-filters-with-meta-fields
- https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#declaring-filterable-fields
- [django Rest Framework filter by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837940/django-rest-framework-filter-by-date-range/60058800#60058800)

views.py:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import viewsets

from my_app.models import MyModel
from my_app.serializers import MySerializer


class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = {'id': ['in']}
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

HTTP request:

- Same as with `filterset_class`

---

### UI rendering error

The HTTP requests performed above are manual, without using the UI provided by `djangorestframework`. Upon trying it with the UI, I experienced the same problem as you stated:

> But this solution doesn't allow me to input commas in the textbox
> anymore.

This is not related to the filtering mechanism provided by `django_filters` (which happens in the backend) as this is a pure frontend issue specifically with the form validation.

A manual workaround I did was inspect the textbox (right-click + inspect) then update the HTML line from `number` to `text`. So from:

```
<input type="number" name="id__in" step="any" id="id_id__in">
```

To:

```
<input type="text" name="id__in" step="any" id="id_id__in">
```

[image]

HTTP Request (numbers):
[image]

HTTP request (numbers and letters):
[image]

You may want to intercept the actual rendering of the HTML by the `djangorestframework` or `django_filters` to do this cleanly.